# Increasing Elasticsearch Field Capacity Effectively

Tags: elasticsearch, capacity

I am running into an issue with the maximum size for a single field/term.

I set my fields to "not_analyzed". 
As you know, it means, "Index this field so it is searchable, but index the value exactly as specified. Do not analyze it." and the maximum size for a single term in the underlying Lucene index is 32766 bytes..

When I try to send over 32766 bytes to my elasticsearch method, that limitation works and do not accept (for example) 40000 characters string.
After my researches, I think I got 2 options;

1-) Continue using the field with "not_analyzed", but use ignore_above setting like below. With this, It will now accept over 32766 bytes but it will not make this field searchable(if it doesnt has to be searchable.).

```
PUT /my_index
        {
          "mappings": {
            "my_type": {
              "properties": {
                "status_code": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "ignore_above": 32766
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

2-) Will mark the index with "no"  option like below. It will accept over 32766 bytes but will not make the field searchable or queryable.

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "status_code": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "no"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My questions are,

-Do these options are able to make cpu or memory impact to my cluster ?

-Do you have any other suggestion for this field capacity?

Thank you for your answers.

UPDATE : I use 1.5.2, so that means, i cant use ignore_above.

Comment: May you please specify your Elasticsearch version? It is not clear if you need this field to be searchable, may you please clarify this?

Comment: question updated.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/mapping-core-types.html#string), `ignore_above` is available in ES 1.5. What is it that you need to do? Do you have problems with performance? Or with memory consumption?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-above.html
there are no 1.5 version ?

Comment: Please refer to the ["String" section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/mapping-core-types.html#string) in the link I posted, there is attribute `ignore_above`, in current ES version `string` data type is represented by 2 data types, `text` and `keyword`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but It did not worked for me my friend..

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but it was merely a hint. I still do not understand what the problem is.

Comment: When I apply "ignore_above: 1 million" to "not_analyzed" field, I expect to insert over 32766 bytes. But I couldn't insert.. what should i do ?

Comment: I think it does not make sense to set `ignore_above` to such a high value. setting it to 1M you practically tell ES to load this in memory and it will finish pretty soon. the search on such a field will not work any fast. so I suggest that you do `index: no` and if you need to do some queries to that field to extract relevant information (say, first 1024 bytes if you want to do prefix searches) and save them in a different field).

Comment: It seems not working in 1.5. I think, I should update my elasticsearch version and use "index":"no" property. That is the best approach.